# Nokogiri, different results of xpath in JRuby

Tags: ruby, jruby, nokogiri, xpath

I am getting different results from the same xpath expression in nokogiri when using ruby and jruby,

In ruby the following xpath expression returns a node while in jruby it returns a nodeset:

```
parent = node.xpath("./ancestor::node()[name(.) = 'div' or name(.) = 'p'][1]")
```

Has anybody else noticed similar behaviour?

Comment: That expression should return the first `div` or `p` ancestor of context node (It would be better without the `./` first step). The problem could be in the type of `node`: Is it a node set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a difference between how libxml2 (used in the MRI Nokogiri) and whatever library the pure-Java version uses in how they handle predicates that match only one node. You should report this to the [nokogiri-talk](http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk) mailing list.

Comment: Thanks, I will bring this up.